# AFRAME - disable cursor gaze on specific elements

Tags: aframe

I'm using the following code for visual feedback:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500" position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive: ring" material="color: black; shader: flat">
    <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1"></a-animation>
    <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-animation>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

The problem is that this code is applied where the cursor "collide" with every primitive entity in the scene. I want it to be apply only on specific elements.  (or alternatively, disable the animations on specific elements). How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `cursor` component depends on the `raycaster` component. If the raycaster component is not added as an attribute of the DOM element, the cursor component will initialize one with default settings. However when provided, you can alter certain attribute values of the raycaster component to satisfy your needs.

Luckily for you, the raycaster component supports specific entities with a DOM query selector.

```
<a-entity cursor raycaster="objects: .clickable"></a-entity>
```

This will make the cursor only emit events to `<a-entity>`s with the class name of `clickable`.

Here is a link to all the raycaster component properties: [raycaster component properties](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/raycaster.html#properties).